# PHP Factorial Issue

Tags: php, html, forms, function, factorial

I am trying to learn PHP and compute the factorial of a number when given a input from a user, but I seem to be stumped. My first and last condition checkout but when I put a number bigger than 2 my result is always false, here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <title>Factorial</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="" method="GET">
        Enter Number: <input type="text" name="num"><br>
        <input type="submit" name ="submit">
    </form>
    Factorial Of Your Number:
    <?php
      function factorial($n){

          if (ctype_digit($n))
          {
              if ($n <= 1)
              {
                  echo "1";
              }
              else
              {
                 echo $n * factorial($n - 1);
              }
          }
          else
          {
            echo "false";
          }
      }
      if(isset($_GET['submit']))
      {
        $s = $_GET["num"];
        factorial($s);
      }
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have tried editing many variations of this line echo $n * factorial($n - 1); but all result in false or an error and I can't seem to crack this. Any ideas? Note that I am trying to keep the php in the internal body not an externalphp file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your recursive function to work, it needs to return a number. Otherwise your function will try to calculate `$n * null` which throws an error.

```
function factorial($n){
    if ($n <= 1) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return $n * factorial($n - 1);
    }
}

if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {
    $n = intval($_GET["num"]);
    echo factorial($n);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

see this solution, find factorial of a given number in PHP?

```
<?php

function findFactorial($num){
  $fact = 1;
  for($i=1; $i<$num+1; $i++){
    $fact = $fact*$i;
  }
  return $fact;

}
$num = 5;
print_r(findFactorial($num));
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here you go:

```
<?php
   $num = $_POST["num"];
   $factorial_value = 1;
   for ($x=$num; $x>=1; $x--)
   {
      $factorial_value = $factorial_value * $x;
   }
   echo "Factorial of $num is $factorial";
?> 

<form method="post">
    Enter a num: 
    <input type="text" name="num">
    <input type="submit" Value="CALCULATE YOUR FACTORIAL"> 
</form>
```

Comment: Im getting an error on calculation- returning value that was inputted

Comment: Code-only answers aren't acceptable on Stack Overflow. And the question was about correctly doing recursion, which this doesn't use.